# I have a problem with this code (cannot resolve method: 'equals( java.lang.String)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char

I'm trying to use this (.equals) method, but it's not working for some reason.

```
 Scanner verb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String verb1 = verb.nextLine();
        char t = verb1.charAt(verb1.length() - 1);

        if(t.equals("t")) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
```

and the error message is this one:

```
cannot resolve method 'equals(java.lang.String)'
```

Comment: chars do not have an `equals()` method... Instead, try `"t".equals(String.valueOf(t))`

Comment: ...Or `t == 't'`

Comment: @Zephyr ... Or `t == 't'`. Far easier, far more efficient.

Comment: I am somewhat curious where or how the error message is getting generated. Eclipse gives this very helpful message, "Cannot invoke equals(String) on the primitive type char"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitives don't have a `equals` method(Primitives don't have any methods). You have to use `==`:

```
if(t == 't') {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

or replace to

```
Character t = verb1.charAt(verb1.length() - 1);

if(t.equals('t')) { // you have to compare 'Character' to 'Character'
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: That seems like it just makes the code more complicated. Why not just handle the char as a primitive?

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a primitive. No primitive has `equals` method. They don't have any members at all. For this code to work, you would have to wrap your `char` using `Character.valueOf(t)` (but then you still have type missmatch you would have to write `equals('t')`) or what would be even easier use `t == 't'`.

Comment: (almost) never use `new` for a value: use `Character.valueOf`. but then, `Character.equals` is never true for a String argument. (Not the downvoter).

Comment: @Andronicus: are you trying to get the [jvm] badge or why are you adding that tag to various questions you've answered? That's not an appropriate tag for most of those questions.

Comment: @JoachimSauer honestly I didn't read the tag description and thought of it as more general tag for jvm-based languages, but I see the purpose of it now. Thanks for stopping me!